# Drupal site is not working

Tags: entities

I have got the following error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '******'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 165 of /home/*****/public_html/******.com/includes/lock.inc)

Thinking of solving that error, I have changed the settings.php file www/mysite/sites/default folder.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'ThemeTesterDB',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '********',
      'host' => 'my host ip',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => 'theme_',
    ),
  ),
);
```

The site is still not working.

Comment: Please don't post your plaintext passwords on the internet, you never know who'll get hold of them :)

Comment: Did you check the old password was correct, or that the username you are using has access to the database engine? Are you sure that `@localhost` user is defined in the database, or that you are connecting to the database from the localhost domain? If the database server is on (for example) 192.168.0.1, using `@localhost` as username could not help.

Comment: If you _are_ connecting to a remote database the problem might be that your server is (correctly) set up to deny remote logins from the root user